# How do i select multiple checkbox have same name and Id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am struggling to find the logic to handle my situation stated below.
please have a look.

I have subject table and it has three subjects. Each subject has unique id.
(Id, Name)

I am displaying each subject on UI as child checkboxe (using `<ul>` element) for 3 different students (parent checkbox using `<li>`).

e.g.

```
Andy
    Math
    English
    Computer
John
    Math
    English
    Computer
Murray
    Math
    English
    Computer
```

**Code:**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h5>Students Courses</h5>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="student in Students">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="{{student[0].Id}}"/>
            <label for="{{student[0].Id}}"><span class="Radiobox-txt" id="{{student[0].Name}}">{{student[0].Name}}</span></label>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="subject in student[0].Subjects">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="{{subject.Id}}" ng-model="subject.Checked" />
                    <label for="{{subject.Id}}"><span id="{{subject.Name}}">{{subject.Name}}</span></label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So, user can select subject under each student and can save it. **The Id of each subject is unique and is coming from Student table.**

**Problem:**
For example, `Math` subject has same `Id` and it is repeated for different student. So, when i select `Math` subject for Murray it basically selects `Math` subject under `Andy` because `Id` is same.

Can someone suggest how i can handle it in better way?

Please note i dont want to have different `Id` of `Math` under different student otherwise it will be wrong becuase i am storig select subject `Id` in my table.
So stored `Id` has to be matched with original `Id` of `subject` table.

Comment: "Please note i dont want to have different Id of Math" — Too bad. An ID **must** be unique in a document.

Comment: can you give a Students object

Comment: you shouldn't need `ng-repeat="subject in student[0].Subjects"` - it should just be `ng-repeat="subject in student.Subjects"` - remove the `[0]` - you're already looping in that student

Comment: @Quentin, if i keep Math Id different for each student and than i select Math for each student and save than Math will have different Id for each student as compared to its oringal id in Subject table. Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using id to store that data in the first place. It sounds more like a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could repeat the selector id with the same name in html, that is against the web standard. You should use `$index` of ng-repeat to make id unique.

The unique id would be for inner ng-repeat would be `{{subject.Id+ $index + $parent.$index}}`

**Markup**

```
    <li ng-repeat="student in Students">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="{{student[0].Id + $index + $parent.$index}}"/>
        <label for="{{student[0].Id+ $index + $parent.$index}}"><span class="Radiobox-txt" id="{{student[0].Name}}">{{student[0].Name}}</span></label>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="subject in student.Subjects">
                <input type="checkbox" id="{{subject.Id+ $index + $parent.$index}}" ng-model="subject.Checked" />
                <label for="{{subject.Id+ $index + $parent.$index}}"><span id="{{subject.Name}}">{{subject.Name}}</span></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: i think your answer make sense to me. Let me give a try.

Comment: adding + $index does not make any different to Id.. i mean id="{{subject.Id+ $index}}" and id="{{subject.Id}}" generates same Id and hence Math Id is repeated under different student. so ended up with same problem.

Comment: @immirza take a look at my update..it will work 100%

Comment: excellent it works for me, However i have one doubt left now... See the orignal Id of Math subject in my Subjects table is '538df185-581b-e511-82ed-303a64efb676' and with the change you suggested the Math id is not '538df185-581b-e511-82ed-303a64efb67601' .. i see 01 is appended in the end which is fine. Now if select Math and save than i believe subject.Id (oringal Id)will be send to database. Right? Adding '$index + $parent.$index' is just differ Id on UI. Hope you get my point.

Comment: @immirza yes you are correct..you are just used it on UI..the value of original id want get modified...Glad to help you.Thanks :)

Comment: excellent thanks you very much. I spent quite good time before posting this question and your answer really help me. great

Answer (score 0):

Use $parent to iterate over the parent loop.

```
<li ng-repeat="student in Students">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="{{student.Id}}"/>
        <label for="{{student.Id}}"><span class="Radiobox-txt" id="{{student[0].Name}}">{{student[0].Name}}</span></label>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="subject in student.Subjects">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{subject.Id}}_{{ $parent}}" ng-model="subject.Checked" />
                <label for="{{subject.Id}}_{{ $parent}}"><span id="{{subject.Name}}">{{subject.Name}}</span></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```